# Content in master page Not Displaying in Content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

I'm using Master page to create my website.
In the master-page I'm using Header, Left side bar and footer. and the strange thing is, if I place the Sidebar Div above the ContentPlaceHolder then the sidebar is not visible and if I place the same Div below the ContentPlaceHolder then the sidebar is visible.

How this is Happening?

Here is the Masterpage Content:

```
<div>
    <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="wrap">

<div id="header">
<div id="topsection"><div class="innertube"><h1>maabookings.com</h1></div></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="leftcolumn" >
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" RenderingMode="List">
<Items>
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Call_Center/Main.aspx" Text="Inbox" Value="inbox"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Processing"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="aslkdjf"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="aslkdjf"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="aslkdjf"></asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
</asp:Menu>
</div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><a href="http://www.maabookings.com/" target="_blank">maabookings</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a css styling issue. Did you do a view source and check if it was rendered in the html

Comment: I do not know how to do it. can you please explain?

Comment: Looks like Css issue.Run you code on Mozilla and User Firebug to check

Comment: could you paste your content from the child page?

Comment: Child page is blank but the masterpage has to be displayed right?

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting these kind of issues you can use FireBug(Firefox Addon) or you can view your View Source(HTML) after the page has rendered.

Once you see this you ll get a clear picture of what needs to be done.